# state_machine only works for new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I can't seem to get the `state_machine` gem (http://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/) to work on existing records (it works correctly on new records).

Here's my model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :state, :initial => :pending do
    event :publish do
      transition all => :published
    end
  end
end
```

and here's an IRB session that demonstrates the issue (I did `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` to make it easier to read):

```
>> c = Comment.new
=> #<Comment id: nil, song_id: nil, author: nil, body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, state: "pending">
>> c.state
=> "pending"
>> c.publish
  Comment Create (0.6ms)   INSERT INTO "comments" ("updated_at", "body", "author", "song_id", "created_at", "state") VALUES('2009-11-02 02:44:37', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2009-11-02 02:44:37', 'published')
=> true
>> Comment.last.state
  Comment Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "comments" ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1
=> "published"
>> c = Comment.create
  Comment Create (0.5ms)   INSERT INTO "comments" ("updated_at", "body", "author", "song_id", "created_at", "state") VALUES('2009-11-02 02:44:47', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2009-11-02 02:44:47', 'pending')
=> #<Comment id: 4, song_id: nil, author: nil, body: nil, created_at: "2009-11-02 02:44:47", updated_at: "2009-11-02 02:44:47", state: "pending">
>> c.publish
=> true
>> c.save
=> true
>> Comment.last.state
  Comment Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "comments" ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1
=> "pending"
```

I.e., everything works fine when I `publish` an unsaved comment, but when I try to publish a comment that's already saved, nothing happens.

## **Another Edit: Perhaps the root of the problem?**

```
=> true
>> a = Comment.last
  Comment Load (1.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "comments" ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Comment id: 3, song_id: nil, author: nil, body: nil, created_at: "2009-11-03 03:03:54", updated_at: "2009-11-03 03:03:54", state: "pending">
>> a.state
=> "pending"
>> a.publish
=> true
>> a.state
=> "published"
>> a.state_changed?
=> false
```

I.e., even though the state has actually changed, `state_changed?` is returning false and therefore Rails won't update the corresponding database row when I call `save`.

**It works when I turn off partial updates, but not when I try `state_will_change!`:**

```
>> Comment.partial_updates = false
=> false
>> c = Comment.create
  Comment Create (0.5ms)   INSERT INTO "comments" ("updated_at", "body", "author", "song_id", "created_at", "state") VALUES('2009-11-07 05:06:49', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2009-11-07 05:06:49', 'pending')
=> #<Comment id: 7, song_id: nil, author: nil, body: nil, created_at: "2009-11-07 05:06:49", updated_at: "2009-11-07 05:06:49", state: "pending">
>> c.publish
  Comment Update (0.9ms)   UPDATE "comments" SET "created_at" = '2009-11-07 05:06:49', "author" = NULL, "state" = 'published', "body" = NULL, "song_id" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2009-11-07 05:06:53' WHERE "id" = 7
=> true
>> Comment.last.state
  Comment Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "comments" ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1
=> "published"
>> Comment.partial_updates = true
=> true
>> c = Comment.create
  Comment Create (0.8ms)   INSERT INTO "comments" ("updated_at", "body", "author", "song_id", "created_at", "state") VALUES('2009-11-07 05:07:21', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2009-11-07 05:07:21', 'pending')
=> #<Comment id: 8, song_id: nil, author: nil, body: nil, created_at: "2009-11-07 05:07:21", updated_at: "2009-11-07 05:07:21", state: "pending">
>> c.state_will_change!
=> "pending"
>> c.publish
=> true
>> c.save
=> true
>> Comment.last.state
  Comment Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "comments" ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1
=> "pending"
```

**EDIT:**

More weirdness:

```
>> a = Comment.last
  Comment Load (1.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "comments" ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Comment id: 5, song_id: nil, author: nil, body: nil, created_at: "2009-11-02 06:33:19", updated_at: "2009-11-02 06:33:19", state: "pending">
>> a.state
=> "pending"
>> a.publish
=> true
>> a.state
=> "published"
>> a.save
=> true
>> a.id
=> 5
>> Comment.find(5).state
  Comment Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."id" = 5) 
=> "pending"
```

Compare to:

```
>> a = Comment.last
  Comment Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "comments" ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Comment id: 5, song_id: nil, author: nil, body: nil, created_at: "2009-11-02 06:33:19", updated_at: "2009-11-02 06:33:19", state: "pending">
>> a.state = "published"
=> "published"
>> a.save
  Comment Update (0.6ms)   UPDATE "comments" SET "state" = 'published', "updated_at" = '2009-11-02 08:29:34' WHERE "id" = 5
=> true
>> a.id
=> 5
>> Comment.find(5).state
  Comment Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."id" = 5) 
=> "published"
```

Comment: Seriously, this is driving me crazy (even my special programming hat (http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/9105/photo2gw.jpg) has been useless)

Comment: :D +1 for the hat!. Anyway, any reason why you're not using the now built in Rails state machine? http://blog.envylabs.com/2009/08/the-rails-state-machine/

Comment: Is it out yet? (`include ActiveRecord::StateMachine` fails on rails 2.3.4 for me)

Comment: Oh! You're right! Really sorry for confusing you. To be honest, I have no experience with this particular plugin, but aasm (http://github.com/rubyist/aasm/) has never failed for me. So maybe try that one. I know, more of a workaround than a solution, but anyway, good luck.

Comment: If I can't figure this out I'll try AASM, but I've found state_machine to be more elegant: you don't have to explicitly declare your states, and when you're writing transitions you can do `:from_state => :to_state` instead of `:from => :from_state, :to => :to_state`

Comment: Can you tell us more about your environment? I just tried your example using Mac OS X 10.6.1/ruby 1.8.7/Rails 2.3.4/state_machine 0.8.0/sqlite3 and it worked fine.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.5.8, ruby 1.8.6, Rails 2.3.4, state_machine 0.8.0, sqlite3

Comment: Have you tried changing your transition to something other than all?
Try expicitly setting your transition eg. 
    :pending => :published

Answer (score 2):

I came over the same issue 3 years after so it worth answering here to save other folks's time.

You need to have column called 'state' in your table, so state_machine will able to make the state persistant.

Just add it to your migration - t.string :state

Answer (score 1):

Can you please retry your state transitions with publish**!** instead of publish

Comment: `publish` and `publish!` have the same effect in the examples above (argh!)

Answer (score 1):

Not contributing anything useful, but I just wanted to say I'm struggling with this error as well, in multiple state_machines throughout my application. And I can't switch to AASM, because I need to have more than one state_machine in the same model... So frustrating!

Anyway, you're not alone, it definitely still needs a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Does this still happen with partial updates turned off? `Comment.partial_updates = false`

If so, then we know the issue is with identifying dirty objects. You should be able to call `c.state_will_change!` before you call `c.publish`

Comment: This is what I was thinking is the likely culprit since your update isn't sending that column.

Comment: Now we're talking! It works when I do `Comment.partial_updates = false`, but not when I do `c.state_will_change!` (see http://pastie.org/687584 for what I did). Unfortunately this model has some big text fields and therefore I'd prefer not to turn off partial updates as a workaround (though I'd implement state_will_change! as a workaround if that worked)

Comment: After `c.state_will_change!` run `c.changed` does the returned array have `"state"` in it?

Comment: Does `update_attribute('state','published')` still work? You might just want to overwrite `publish!` to make the update call manually...

Comment: `update_attribute('state','published')` works, but if I'd prefer not to break `state_machine`'s abstraction like that...

Comment: From http://pastie.org/689749 it definitely looks like dirty updates are broken. Do dirty updates work with any other ActiveRecord model that doesn't use the state machine? Are you using any other plugins/gems that may be trying to duplicate dirty behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Does the model call super when it's initialized?

The state_machine documentation says it's required for states to get initialized

```
def initialize
  @seatbelt_on = false
  super() # NOTE: This *must* be called, otherwise states won't get initialized
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, not a real answer to your question, but here I tried to simulate your session:

```
>> c = Comment.new
=> #<Comment id: nil, body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, state: "pending">
>> c.state
=> "pending"
>> c.publish
=> true
>> Comment.last.state
=> "published"
>> c = Comment.create
=> #<Comment id: 4, body: nil, created_at: "2009-11-05 07:12:53", updated_at: "2009-11-05 07:12:53", state: "pending">
>> c.publish
=> true
>> c.save
=> true
>> Comment.last.state
=> "published"
```

As you can see, it works as expected for me. Checked it twice.
(I created a model with body and state attributes and put your code in it.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove :state from definition:

FROM:
state_machine :state , :initial => :pending do

TO
state_machine :initial => :pending do